# The constructor of the subclass inherited from the generic singleton base class must require public permissions. How to solve it?

Tags: c#, constructor, parent-child

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : Singleton<T>, new()
{
    public static T Instance => _instance;
    private static readonly T _instance = new T();

    static Singleton(){}

    protected Singleton(){}
}

public sealed class UIModelCollection:Singleton<UIModelCollection>
{
    //error CS0310
    private UIModelCollection(){ }
    //Resolve after declaring as public
}
```

What kind of singleton do I use for a constructor with public permissions...
 
This is stumping me.
 
Now I have to initialize something in the constructor with private permissions.
 
How should I write it?

Comment: `How should I write it?` Change `private` to `public`.

Comment: But it's a singleton class...I can't change it easily just like it.

Comment: Read the link. `, new()` means you need a public constructor.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38522/Design-Flaws-of-the-Singleton-Pattern-in-C

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! Thanks for your guys. That's helped me a lot.